# Spark Dynamic Resource Allocation and Queued Applications

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

According to this [Cloudera documentation](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/cdh_ig_running_spark_on_yarn.html#spark_on_yarn_dynamic_allocation):

> When Spark dynamic resource allocation is enabled, all resources are allocated to the first submitted job available causing subsequent applications to be queued up. To allow applications to acquire resources in parallel, allocate resources to pools and run the applications in those pools and enable applications running in pools to be preempted.

I've observed this behaviour myself, however I'm currently working on a small cluster with only 2 nodes (m3.xlarge on EMR) and 1 master (r3.xlarge). What I'm seeing is that if I submit multiple spark applications (different calls to `spark-submit`), when I look up my resource manager on EMR, all the applications get accepted but only one is ever running at a time.

Now this might be due to the fact that I'm reading in files that are roughly 2GB and that my resources are maxed out. I've also tried making a few `spark-submit` calls with the existing `pi.py` examples from Spark. In that case, I can see more than a single job in a running state.

Given that, is the Cloudera documentation correct or is it misleading? If I were to have a much larger cluster, would I see more than one of my applications running in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

**Spark Dynamic Allocation**

Dynamic Allocation comes with the policy of scaling executors up and down as follows:

Scale Up Policy requests new executors when there are **pending tasks** and increases the number of executors exponentially since executors start slow and Spark application may need slightly more.

Scale Down Policy removes executors that have been idle for spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout seconds.

**Cloudera Resource to pools**

So what the cloudera is saying is, There might be a single job might take all the resources due to **tasks pending** , please create the yarn ques and allocate specific amount of resource per ques. Please follow the link how to create the yarn ques.

https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/201623853-How-to-configure-queues-using-YARN-capacity-scheduler-xml

**In Above Case** 
**Scenario 1**

In your job there might be more **pending task** and most of the resource are allocated to single job due to dynamic resource allocate, even though you submitted next application it will be waited state due to resource .

**Scenario 2**

when you run those examples the resources required by jobs might be less tasks and dynamic allocation not spinning more executors(because no pending tasks). As there are extra(unalocated) resources in the cluster next multiple applications are running instead of waiting state.

Comment: Regarding my example, there are two different scenarios:  

1) I submit multiple "large" applications. By that I mean that these applications will require a lot of memory to process. In this scenario, the applications are all accepted and queued up but only one is running at a time.  

2) I submit multiple "small" applications like the existing example to calculate Pi. Here I can see multiple applications that are in a running state at the same time.  

So in the latter case, all the resources were not used up by a single application otherwise I wouldn't see multiple tasks "running"?